# Graphics bug using nVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Good morning! I need some explanations, i'm using nvidia drivers on ubuntu 14.04 with nVidia 820m two dedicated gb and i have some strange bug moving the windows. If i use nouvea i have no problem but my fps fall down to 60( with nvidia 1200 at full screen). Is there anyone who can help me to understand? I installed 340.76 downloaded from nvidia website. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: Thank you!! To be honest i don't know what a PPA is or why PPA is needed so you do you think this PPA will improve my situation?? How can i install it?

Comment: @david-foerster: Thanks for the edit.  Jacapo: a PPA is a software repository *outside* the normal Ubuntu channels and one of the [few vectors for malware](https://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/) on Linux.  Therefore, read both links, and make a sound *personal judgement* whether you want to continue or not. That being said, a PPA with 1000s of users, referenced all over the Internet is probably safer then PPA:Maffia.IT/BotNet...  ;-)

Comment: I'm not an expert in ubuntu what ppa do you advise me?

Comment: Thank you Fabby i installed xorg and x-swat which is better? I have the same problem with both ppa. System settings > software and updates from here i can select the ppa if both are selected what will happen? Thank you very much you're helping to understand how ubuntu works

Comment: go to a terminal and type: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` to install the PPA, then: `sudo update` to get the software list and then you should have a bunch of nvidia drivers available.  to see them all type: `apt-cache search nvidia | grep --ignore-case binary | grep version`

Comment: I've never done this outside chat, so you have to be careful!  I would start with the latest and greatest driver: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346`  Then try everything out and report back. (90% chance of success).  Oh and as you're a 1 reputation user: don't forget to click the little grey check-mark under the "0" to accept the answer if it all works out as this means "yes, this answer is valid!"

Comment: I have another problem now...i tried to install the 346 but i think i'm in 10% you said. Actually i'm using nouveau if i select nVidia driver in system settings and reboot i will nave a fantastic black screen!! I have tried different guide but no one has helped me. I purged nVidia and tried to install from the terminal nVidia 340 or nVidia current but nothing can you help me??

Comment: so if I get you right, you already tried: 331.113 (current) 340.76 (newer) and (346.35).  then the only thing you can still do is: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-304` (oldest). If that doesn't work, the only option I'll have for a few weeks is to disable the NVidia card until the new driver comes out... :(